# Given an equation, Show it is identical and find the possible values of cotx.

Tags: trigonometry

Full question:

Given that: $2\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 1$

Show that $\cos^2(x) = 2\sin^2(x)$

I've done that part.

The next part is: Hence find the possible values of $\cot(x)$.

I divided by $\sin^2(x)$ to give me

$\cot(x) = 2$

So ${1\over \tan(x)} = 2$

$x =\arctan(0.5) = 0.46$

${1\over \tan(0.46)} = 2.$

Answer says $+/-2^.5$                  ...(Root 2)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake happens in the middle: You divided by $\sin^2(x)$ to give you $\cot^2(x) = 2$, not $\cot(x) = 2$. Also note that we're not after values of $x$, we're after values of $\cot(x)$. So no reason to go so far as to use $\tan^{-1}$ here; you can stop the moment you have something "$\cot(x) = \cdots$"